# Duplicar el texto de un Textview

Tags: android

Amigos estoy realizando un chat y tengo la opcion de que si la persona mantiene pulsado un mensaje en este caso con onItemLongClick puedo hacer mostrar un alert donde le diga pueda borrarlo o no , la duda surge cuando deseo hacer que el usuario dezlice y el texto de ese textview se copie en mi EditText para que pueda responderlo asi como es Whatsapp , hay alguna forma chicos?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto puede ayudarte

Primero implementa View.OnTouchListener

```
public class chat extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

//sobrescribis el metodo que solicita con:
        switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Este lo utilizo para tomar posiciones iniciales de donde esta el texto
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //aca deberias implementar la logica de que cuando muevas el texto y llegue a determinado punto X realize algo
                break;
        }
        return (motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
}
```

Luego desde el onStart() o onCreate() el que decidas y uses, yo generalmente el onStart() para estas cosas, asignas esto

```
tuView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Te dejo mi codigo de demostracion, es una imagen que al moverla para la izquierda o derecha, realizo determinada accion dependiendo donde se movio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]